# Reasons for Bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I just started a bounty on [a question of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/366857/why-is-the-same-graphics-card-slower-in-a-different-machine), when I was asked for the reason why. Unfortunately none of the answers I could select were totally applicable. If I had the choice, I would have liked the option:

> This question has not yet to received an answer which solves the original problem.

Instead I had to choose:

> This question has not received enough attention.

Why is this? It's always been the reason I've started bounties - I have a problem that needs solving, and none of the answers have solved it.

Comment: Also, FWIW, it's kind of crumby that you still lose your bounty, even if no-one can answer your question for you, but I guess I understand why that is.

Comment: As an aside, you _can_ add a custom message to expand on your reasons for adding the bounty to clarify your intentions.

Comment: Yep, I did that on the question I linked to, but just so you know: The clarifications are actually for what you want in return for your bounty, not to clarify why you created the bounty in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't seem that your bounty statement explains what you want. Unless it's a faster PC, but then 50 rep doesn't even cover shipping ;)

Comment: @DanielBeck, It's 200 rep? Also, the bounty statement is an additional clarification, not an outright statement... Otherwise it would take the place of the original question, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: And I wasn't even on drugs when I posted my comment :-) 200 rep still doesn't cover the cost of a new PC though! // In all seriousness, with the last part of my post I meant that you should state what you expect of an acceptable answer, i.e. is an explanation sufficient, does it have to be replicable; or do you require a fix? Is it acceptable to show that you cannot fix it?

Comment: I have no idea what the difference between an "explanation", a "replicable explanation", and a "fix" is, so I can't say for sure. If it can't be done, it can't be done, but I'd expect a full explanation as to why!

Comment: I recently had the same problem, I opened a bounty, originally to get more attention to the question because I hadn't recieved an appropriate answer yet. Well, even after I opened the bounty I still didn't get an answer, so I let the bounty expire thinking I'd get it back. There should have been a warning because if I knew all that Rep was just going to disappear I would have awarded it to whoever tried the hardest to help answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning you give to a bounty is *not about why* you gave the bounty; it is there to guide the visitors to your question **what you are looking for with your bounty**, this can be clearly seen in bold:

> **Authoritative reference needed**
>     Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
>
> **Canonical answer required**
>     The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.
>
> **Current answers are outdated**
>     The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
>
> **Draw attention**
>     This question has not received enough attention.
>
> **Improve details**
>     The current answers do not contain enough detail.
>
> **Reward existing answer**
>     One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

`not yet received an answer which solves the problem` falls under **Draw attention**;  because you basically haven't gotten attention yet from an expert that does know a solution to your problem. So, by giving a bounty you state that you are looking for more attention with reputation in return...

Comment: So I chose correctly, but it wasn't clear to me, as a user.